# Check if key of one array exists as value in other array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**The situation:**

I have two arrays:

- availablePersons
  In this array I have all my available Persons. The Userid is entered here. When I use

  console.log(availablePersons)

I get the following:

```
0: 6
1: 7
2: 8
```

- summary
  In this array I have all selected persons and as value the count of how many times they where selected (the Key is the Userid).
  console.log result is this:

  6: 5
  7: 1

**What I should get**

I need to check now for each person in availablePersons if they exist in the summary array.
So check if each value of the availablePersons Array exists as key in the summary array.

When there is one person, which doesn't exists in the summary array I need to do something.

**My code**

```
for (var i=0; i<availablePersons.length; i++){
  for (var j=0; j<summary.length; j++){
    if(summary[j] !== availablePersons[i]) {
      $('#person-'+i+' .person-sum').text('0');
      $('#person-'+i).fadeIn();
      $('#person-'+i).css('background-color', '#FF0000'); 
      console.log( $('#person-'+i) );
    }
  }
}
```

**The problem**

The console.log outputs

selector: "#person-0" and so on until selector: "#person-2".

But it should be the userid (in my case 6, 7 or 8).

Comment: You're using an array, it doesn't really have keys, just indices, and if you have one single index with the "key" 10, then the length will also be 10, so you're failing as you should be using an object and a `for-in` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since availablePerson is an array, use `forEach` to iterate over it:

```
availablePerson.forEach(function(n) {
    // argument n holds the UserId. Doing console.log(n) you see:
    // first step: 6, second step: 7, third step 8
    if (summary[n]) { // check if index[n] is defined ("if UserId is in summary")
       /* here you can do something if User is already there */
    } else { // if UserId is not in summary run your code
        // your i (= index of availablePerson) is changed to n (=UserId);
        $('#person-'+n+' .person-sum').text('0');
        $('#person-'+n).fadeIn();
        $('#person-'+n).css('background-color', '#FF0000'); 
        console.log( $('#person-'+n) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the entries in `availablePersons` that are not in the summary, try this:

```js
// SAMPLE - real data obtained dynamically.
var availablePersons = [6, 7, 8];
var summary = {6: 5, 7: 1};

// For each available person in the list...
for (var i = 0; i < availablePersons.length; i++) {

  // If that person is NOT in the summary data...
  if (typeof summary[availablePersons[i]] === 'undefined') {

    // Do whatever it is you need to do.
    alert('Did not find ' + availablePersons[i]);
  }
}
```

Note that `availablePersons` is an Array, but `summary` is an Object.  What this does is take the current entry in `availablePersons` and use that as the key in `summary`, testing whether such a key as been defined.

**EDIT**: If `summary` is an Array and you cannot change that, then try this:

```js
// SAMPLE - real data obtained dynamically.
var availablePersons = [6, 7, 8];
var summary = [];
summary[6] = 5;
summary[7] = 1;

// Set up a variable we'll use repeatedly.
var foundPerson;

// For each available person in the list...
for (var i = 0; i < availablePersons.length; i++) {
  
  // Note that we have not yet found this person in the summary array.
  foundPerson = false;
  
  // See if they exist in the summary array.
  for (var j = 0; j < summary.length; j++) {
    
    // If this is an empty index in the summary array, skip it.
    if (summary[j] === undefined) {
      continue;
    }
    
    // If this summary entry is the person we were looking for...
    if (typeof summary[availablePersons[i]] !== 'undefined') {
      
      // Make a note that we found them.
      foundPerson = true;
      
      // Stop searching the summary array for this person.
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // If we did NOT find the person in the summary array...
  if ( ! foundPerson) {
    
    // Do whatever it is you need to do.
    alert('Did not find ' + availablePersons[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my arrays/objects are getting generated dynamically every time. so I don't know which userids exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are using the second array indices to act as keys for the first array values.
Kindly check if this will help:

```
var availablePersons = [1,5,6];
var summary = Array(10);
summary[5]=10; //Lets say the availablePerson 5 has summary 10 and others did have a summary.
for(i=0;i<availablePersons.length;i++){
    if(summary[availablePersons[i]]==null){
        console.log(availablePersons[i]+" is not there!");
    }
}
```